# pyrocms assign count to variable

Tags: php, pyrocms

I would like to check if is last post from loop. I am using pyroCMS. But problem is that if i am using `helper:count` two times it is not working correctly. How can i assign `helper:count` to variable and use later variable. Is this possible?

```
{{ blog:posts limit="5" order-by="title" order-dir="desc" }}

{{ if { helper:count mode="subtract" } == blog:all_posts}}

                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url }}" title="Read more about: {{ title }}">
                    <span class="naslovna_datum_novice">{{ helper:date format="d.m.Y" timestamp=created_on }} - </span>
                        {{ title }}
                    </a>
                </li>

                {{ elseif { helper:count mode="subtract" } == 5 }}

                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url }}" title="Read more about: {{ title }}">
                    <span class="naslovna_datum_novice">{{ helper:date format="d.m.Y" timestamp=created_on }} - </span>
                        {{ title }}
                    </a>
                </li>

                {{ else }}

                <li class="pikce_spodaj">
                    <p>
                        <a href="{{ url }}" title="Read more about: {{ title }}">
                        <span class="naslovna_datum_novice">{{ helper:date format="d.m.Y" timestamp=created_on }} - </span>
                        {{ title }}
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </li>   

                {{ endif }}

{{ /blog:posts }}
```

So how to assign `{{ helper:count mode="subtract" }}` to variable?? How to assign anything to variable?

Comment: Will it work to use the "identifier" attribute of helper:count, if you have two counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a simpler way; the streams core code adds a `last` property to the final item in an array - [source code](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/3.0/develop/system/cms/modules/streams_core/models/row_m.php#L1097%5D%20so%20you%20can%20check%20this%20with%20a%20conditional%3a) - that you can just query with a conditional:

```
{{ if last }} foo {{ endif }}
```

(The source code that does that is

Here's a working example for blogs I've just tested:

```
{{ blog:posts limit="5" order_by="title" }}
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>

    [...]

    {{ if last }}<p>This is the last item</p>{{ endif }}
{{ /blog:posts }}
```

Also, as Nick points out, you can have more than one counter.